# Shopping Cart Question using radio buttons to retrieve values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a shopping cart using javascript and html with the goal of merging this into a database after more progress.  I have the following HTML for radio buttons:

```
  <!--------------------------------HTML START---------------------------------->
  <div class="shop-item">
                <span class="shop-item-title">Steak</span>
                <div class="shop-item-details">
                    <span class="shop-item-price">$12.99</span>

  <button  class="modalbtn-primary shop-item-button-header" type="button" data-modal-target="#modal">ADD TO CART</button> <!--btn btn-primary shop-item-button--->

  <div class="modal" id="modal">
  <div class="title">How would you like it cooked?
    <div class="shop-items">
    <div class="shop-item">      
  <div data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="row">   
        <input type="radio" class="shop-item-temp" id="temp" name = "temp" value="Wrong">Rare
        <input type="radio" class="shop-item-temp" id="temp" name = "temp" value="Medium Rare">Medium Rare              
        <input type="radio" class="shop-item-temp" id="temp" name = "temp" value="Medium" checked>Medium
        <input type="radio" class="shop-item-temp" id="temp" name = "temp" value="Medium Well">Medium Well
        <input type="radio" class="shop-item-temp" id="temp" name = "temp" value="Well">Well
    </div>
  </div> 
<!--------------------------------HTML END---------------------------------->

//Then I have the following Javascript to try to get the values


//start javascript for click event to add items to cart.  Popup for selecting temperature of meat

function addToCartClicked(event) {
 var button = event.target
 var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
 var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText

    //var temp = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-temp')[0].checked  -- this works but only adds the 1st value Rare
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = ""; 
        var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

        for(i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) { 

            if(temp[i].type="radio") { 

                if(temp[i].checked) 
                    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML 
                            += temp[i].name +
                            + temp[i].value + "<br>"; 
            } 
        } 

 var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
 addItemToCart(title,temp, price)
 updateCartTotal()
}


function addItemToCart(title, temp, price) {//temp, , , imageSrc
 var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
 cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
 var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
 var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')


for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
    if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
        alert('This item is already added to the cart')
        return
    }
}
//end javascript
```

I get the Steak, price and quantity but I get [object HTMLCollection] instead of the temperature of the steak.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "temperature" is the attribute "value" of your radio items.

`<input type="radio" class="shop-item-temp" id="temp" name = "temp" value="Medium Rare">Medium Rare`

Right after checking that the attribute is "checked" `if (temp[i].checked)` you can have your temperature like this:

```
temperature = temp[i].getAttribute("value");
```

Extra remark, on my code I would prefer using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for this kind of for loop.